# Immutable data structure or const variable?

Tags: c++, copy

When I write a class, it's always a big issue whether to make *immutable class* or just use *`const` keyword*.

I came from Objective-C, and when I used Objective-C, there was separated mutable/immutable convention. This is mainly because lack of `const` semantic like in C++, but it also guarantees immutability of object and especially I can trap when a immutable object is being copied to mutable object. So I could use shared state for immutable objects, and copies state only when it is being copied to mutable object.

In C++, there's `const` semantics, so I tried to design a container with it, but I have a few issues with it. Here's sample code.

```
struct Foo
{
  int bar;
};

Foo const f1;
Foo f2 = f1;    // This is allowed but...
```

Copy assignment from `f1` to `f2` is allowed, and doesn't make any warning or error. The problem is I cannot trap the situation of copying immutable object to mutable object. When I write a copy-assignment constructor, it's for both of mutable or immutable object. I want to make immutable object to use shared state, and it will be copied only when it is being copied to mutable object.

Copy-on-write is not for me because my container code should be appropriate for real-time program. Performance hit must be visible and the position should be predictable. Copy-on-write   is not allowed because it defers copying cost to unpredictable time point. Copy cost must be visible.

This can be solved by making separated object for each immutable/mutable object, but I am not sure this is good design on C++.

What is recommended pattern to make immutable/mutable classes with visible copying cost? I think this can be solve if I can make some *copy constructor from immutable to mutable*, but I cannot find any method.

Comment: You probably shouldn't implement both. I'd just implement the mutable with const semantics and then let the user wrap it in a shared_ptr if they want to prevent copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pointers:

```
const Foo *f1 = new Foo(); /* Foo instance is trapped in pointer-to-const */
//Foo *f2 = f1; /* Error; not allowed without cast. */
Foo *f3 = new Foo(*f1); /* Use copy constructor */
delete f1;
delete f3;
```

With shared_ptr(C++11):

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<Foo> f1 = std::make_shared<Foo>(); /* shared_ptr will not implicitly copy object */
std::shared_ptr<Foo> f2 = f1; /* No copy made */
std::shared_ptr<Foo> f3 = std::make_shared<Foo>(*f1); /* use copy constructor */
```

If the client uses the object directly, THEY take responsibility for the copy overhead. This is more or less expected. You can hide the overhead by using pointers/refcounting/copy-on-write internally in your class, but as you said, this isn't what you want.